# Is Boost stacktrace async signal safe?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

Boost has [boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace.html) that can be used to get backtraces. This is normally useful in non-signal handling contexts such as exceptions, errors, etc.

But is it safe to be called from a signal handler? i.e., it doesn't do any async-signal-unsafe activities? The example does use it from a signal handler which might mean it is safe. But I can't find anything in its documentation about [async-signal-safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.handle_terminates_aborts_and_seg has:

> **Warning**
> Writing a signal handler requires high attention! Only a few system calls allowed in signal handlers, so there's no cross platform way to print a stacktrace without a risk of deadlocking. The only way to deal with the problem - dump raw stacktrace into file/socket and parse it on program restart.
>
> **Warning**
> Not all the platforms provide means for even getting stacktrace in async signal safe way. No stack trace will be saved on such platforms.

Immediately followed by:

```
#include <signal.h> // ::signal, ::raise
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void my_signal_handler(int signum) {
    ::signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("./backtrace.dump");
    ::raise(SIGABRT);
}
```

It goes on with usage examples, and how to do start up checks

Header synopis: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/stacktrace/reference.html#header.boost.stacktrace.safe_dump_to_hpp

```
namespace boost {
  namespace stacktrace {
    std::size_t safe_dump_to(void *, std::size_t);
    std::size_t safe_dump_to(std::size_t, void *, std::size_t);
    std::size_t safe_dump_to(const char *);
    std::size_t safe_dump_to(std::size_t, std::size_t, const char *);
    std::size_t safe_dump_to(platform_specific_descriptor);
    std::size_t safe_dump_to(std::size_t, std::size_t, 
                             platform_specific_descriptor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Contrary to my claim, the async-signal-safety of boost backtace APIs are documented quite well, albeit in headers and other locations than the main doc page. Thanks for the links. There's no yes or no answer for async-signal-safety of Boost's backtrace APIs as it depends on the specific API - most of them are safe while others are not.

Comment: I think most of them are not, except for the `safe_`-family of functions which are documented to be

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is**.

As, the function provided in boost library for dumping the backtrace is `boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to`.

And the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/stacktrace/safe_dump_to_idp748512480.html) of `safe_dump_to` clearly states `Async-Handler-Safety: Safe`